# Fazer pesquisa com datas usando MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem? Espero que sim.
Estou com dúvidas em relação a ordenar os dados do banco de dados em ordem crescente de datas.
var resultado = from r in context.nome
where r.numero == 2
orderby r.datacadastro
select r;

Mas não retornar com datas ordenadas. ele ordena por dia.
exemplo:
01/09/2020
02/10/2019
03/02/2014
07/09/2020...
Acredito que tenha alguma coisa a ver com o Sql Server estar cadastrado com datas em americano e o VS está retornando as datas em pt, ou vice versa. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Apresente um [MCVE]

Comment: No seu banco de dados, essas datas estão cadastradas em um campo do tipo Date/Datetime? Pois pelo que você descreveu, é como se ele estivesse retornando as datas em "ordem alfabética/numérica", desconsiderando a ordenação por data e sim considerando como uma string.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, Marcio!

Acho que o exemplo abaixo irá te ajudar:

```
var resultado = context.nome.OrderByDescending(c => c.datacadastro).ToList();
```

Algo nesse sentido.

Abraços!